# How to refresh/re-compile scripts in dom after removing of script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove script and after that, function as `$('body').click(function (e) {` has not to work, because it is located in removed that script.

i do:

```js
$('script[src^="app/common/kendoGridExtendedHelper.js?1"]').remove();
```

buuuut after `$('body').click(function (e) {` keeps working and i can see this script in browser by dev tools.

Help please

Comment: Once the script is loaded, it is loaded. You can't *unload* it. You can only remove events (no need to remove the tag) like `$('body').off('click')`.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, please show me, what can i do for inner function doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like you're assuming. When the script runs and the click event handler is attached to `'body'`, it's in the DOM already, and nothing you do with the script tag will change that.

You'll have to **remove the handler** in your own script, just do:

```
$('body').off('click');
```

This can be messy, and break other functionalities, as **every click handler** is going to be removed from `'body'`. The ideal approach for this cases is to **use namespaces**. If you have control in that script you were trying to remove, attach the click handler with a namespace:

```
$('body').on('click.somenamespace', function () { ... });
```

And then in your script detach it using the same namespace:

```
$('body').off('click.somenamespace');
```

Comment: You cannot unload the script. If you have control on the html page, just remove the script tag!! If you don't, it's some kind of attack/hack on the page what you're trying to do, you might have the best reasons, but technically it is.